# Differentiate between finger touch and hand/palm rest

Tags: android, ios, touch, multi-touch

Is there any technique to differentiate between finger touch and palm rest on surface while drawing on touch surface <del>in iOS</del> touch based os?

Edit : Added **android** tag as question is relevant for any touch based os.

Thanks

Comment: +1, Was about to ask the same question!

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for Android systems, but on iOS I do not believe there is any definitive distinction as all touches, regardless of surface area' are resolved to individual points.

That said, there are ways you could determine whether a specific touch is a palm or finger. If you are making a hand-writing App for instance, if you ask the user whether they are left or right handed then you could ignore all touches to the right/left of the touch that would logically be the finger/stylus. Your method for eliminating the "palm touches" would be specific to the App you are writing.

Something else I have noticed (although I hasten to add this is not particularly reliable!) is that a palm touch will often result in many small touches around the palm area rather than a single touch due to the shape of the palm, small palm movement/rolling, etc. If you know you only ever need to receive and use one touch, this may be something you can manipulate.

In the end, any technique you use to differentiate a palm touch from a finger touch will probably be logical, rather than API/hardware-available. Again, this is iOS specific I am not at all familiar with Android's touch system.